# GUI design for plotting boxplot

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

let us suppose that we have following  GUI 
[image]

idea is following: user enters the input  or number of variables, and  then in cycle  he will enter  step by step that amount of variables, for instance let us suppose that  number of variables is 5
so  user enter 1, then clicks enter and   cell will be empty, then enters 2 ,  then enter and  so on and result will be  saves in pre-allocated array,here is code

```
n=str2num(get(handles.observation_number,'String'));
array=zeros(1,n);
for ii=1:n
    array(ii)=str2num(get(handles.variables,'String'));
end
axes(handles.axes1);
boxplot(array);
```

but program does not gives me possibility to do that, how can i fix it? thanks in advance

Comment: if someone   clicks close tag, he or she should explain reason

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a callback function, something like:

```
enterVar=uicontrol('Style', 'edit','Callback',{@addVar});
```

Where addVar is a function that assign the current value to the last empty position of "array" variable and erase the content of the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the inputdlg() in your place:

```
for ii=1:n
    prompt = {'Enter a variable:'};
    dlg_title = 'Input';
    num_lines = 1;
    answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines);
    array(ii) = str2double(answer);
end
```